# How to not disable triggers during deployment in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-server-data-tools, database-project, dacpac

When deploying SQL Server Database projects (using either the SSDT Publish wizard or DACPAC deployment), the **automated SQL scripts starts by disabling all triggers**.

How do I avoid this?

And what are the side effects of not disabling triggers?

```
PRINT N'Disabling all DDL triggers...'
GO
DISABLE TRIGGER ALL ON DATABASE
GO
<ALL DB CHANGES>
GO
PRINT N'Reenabling DDL triggers...'
GO
ENABLE TRIGGER [LogSchemaChanges] ON DATABASE
GO
PRINT N'Update complete.';
```

Why would I do this? We have a trigger that logs all schema changes to an audit log. 
*...and Isn't it ironic, don't you think...*

Comment: this is definitely an option you can switch on or off

Comment: Side effect would be those triggers would fire... and you'd see the performance hit.

Answer (score 3):

For manual **Publish Wizard** deployment, change the behaviour under:

1. Advanced Publish Settings > General > Advanced Deployment Options.
2. Deselect the "Disable and reenable DDL triggers".

For automated **DACPAC** deployment via SQLPackage, set the following [publish property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage?view=sql-server-2017#publish-parameters-properties-and-sqlcmd-variables):

```
/p:DisableAndReenableDdlTriggers=False
```

*Specifies whether Data Definition Language (DDL) triggers are disabled at the beginning of the publish process and re-enabled at the end of the publish action.*

Comment: ** Note that using DisableAndReenableDdlTriggers flag make triggers ENABLED again just BEFORE Post-Deployment Script starts **
This means that Post-Deployment scripts will be executed with all triggers enabled again

Comment: It took me a couple tries to figure it out, but the commnand line did not like the spaces around the =  .  I had to use: /p:DisableAndReenableDdlTriggers=False